# How can I load a Drupal Form via ajax into a jQuery dialog?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-7

I have a module in which I build a form. I can hit form via a menu item that was also created in that module. When I try to load the form via ajax I get the entire page (header, form and footer) instead of just the form. Here's the menu item:

```
$items['sendmessage'] = array(
   'title' => 'Send Message',
   'description' => 'Send a message',
   'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments' => array('rmessages_message_form', 1),
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$('.send_message').click(function(){
   $('.send-message-dialog').dialog('open');
      $('.send-message-dialog .dialog-content').load('/sendmessage/7');
   }
);
```

If I load the URL via a browser, the form loads. Is there some way to get drupal to just render the form and return the HTML rather than trying to load the entire page.

---

This seems to be working...gotta remember the drupal_render function ;)

```
$items['sendmessage'] = array(
   'page callback' => 'rmessage_send_message_form',
   'page arguments' => array('rmessages_message_form', 1),
   'access callback' => TRUE
);
```

Using drupal_build_form to get an array of items, which gets rendered by drupal_render()

```
function rmessage_send_message_form($form_id, $nid) {
   $form_state = array();
   echo drupal_render(drupal_build_form('rmessages_message_form', $form_state, $nid));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the nicest way to do it would be to have your form accessible from the normal URL (for those without JavaScript) *and* available to AJAX. You can do that like this:

```
function rmessage_menu() {
  $items['sendmessage/%node'] = array( // Using the '%node' load argument ensures that the nid attempting to be accessed belongs to an existing node.
    'title' => 'Send Message',
    'description' => 'Send a message',
    'page callback' => 'rmessages_message_form',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );

  return $items;
}

function rmessages_message_form($node) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('rmessage_send_message_form', $node->nid);

  // Just print the form directly if this is an AJAX request
  if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo render($form);

    // Halt page processing
    drupal_exit();
  }

  // Otherwise return the form as normal
  return $form;
}
```

Then in your JS you would just need to add the query string:

```
$('.send_message').click(function(){
   $('.send-message-dialog').dialog('open');
      $('.send-message-dialog .dialog-content').load('/sendmessage/7?ajax');
   }
);
```

Hope that helps